# When are $ r_1: ax + by + c=0 $ and $ r_2: a'x + b'y + c'=0$ distinct?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

When are $ r_1: ax + by + c=0 $ and $ r_2: a'x + b'y + c'=0$ distinct? I think, if $$rank\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ 
a' & b'
\end{array} \right)\neq 1$$ then $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct. Is correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not correct: take for example $a=a',\ b=b'$ and $c\ne c'$. (I assume that you mean $\text{rank}\begin{bmatrix} a& b \\ a' & b'\end{bmatrix} =1$)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, ok if $a=a'$ and $b=b'$ then $rnk=1$, therefore are not distinct..

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, if ${rank}\begin{bmatrix} a& b \\ a' & b'\end{bmatrix} =1$ then are parallel, is correct?

Comment: Yes they are parallel

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, if $rank\begin{bmatrix} a& b&c \\ a' & b'&c'\end{bmatrix} =2$ then $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct, is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case1: rnk=1 and c/c′ in not an integer,
case2: rnk≠1 and c=c′. 
In the first case they are parallel and distint and in the second case they are not parallel and distinct. Consider any two lines they should be parallel ,coincide or not parallel. Thus these two are the only possibibilities for r1 and r2 to be distinct.